# SQL server 2014 Transaction Log Backup fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, maintenance

I have setup a Maintenance Plan for my SQL server 2014 Database. This Plan Generates Full Backup every Sunday, and Differential backup every Day and Transaction Log every hour.

This Maintenance plan worked fine initially, but now after few successful backups the Transaction Log backups are failing (specially during Production Hours).

When i restart the SQL server instance, then the Backups are generated fine again until the production hours (work hours). My Database is around 40Gb.

So what is causing this Backups to fail during Production hours? Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Installed SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (SP1) and that resolved the issue.